# Why does comparison function type need to specified as template parameter?

Tags: c++, stl

For associative containers in C++, like set, map etc, we need to provide the custom key comparator type as a template parameter as follows.

```
bool compareMyType(const MyType& a, const MyType& b);

set<MyType, decltype(compareMyType)*> my_set(compareMyType); // OK
set<MyType> my_set(compareMyType); // ERROR
```

Why is this required? Why can't the type of comparator function be deduced by the type of key?

Comment: `set<MyType, bool(*)(MyType const&, MyType const&)>` would have worked as well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike functions, there is no partial deduction for class templates.  If you provide template parameters to a class template then you need to provide all non defaulted parameters, and in `set`'s case you need to provide the comparison type since it defaults to `std::less<T>`, which your function pointer is not convertible to.

There was a proposal to get partial deduction, but it was rejected and the only current thing being added to CTAD is that it will work through an alias.

Comment: Do you happen to know *why* it was rejected?

Comment: @Aconcagua Unfortunately I do not.  I think [Barry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2069064/barry) might though.  He was the one who informed me partial deduction was dropped.

Answer (score 2):

Your question has been answered so this is just input to how you could work around the problem:

You could supply `operator<` for your type to avoid having to supply a less functor for it every time you use it in a `set`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

struct MyType {
    int value;
};

// added operator<
bool operator<(const MyType& l, const MyType& r) {
    return l.value < r.value;
}

int main() {
    std::set<MyType> my_set = {{3}, {2}, {1}};
    for(const MyType& m : my_set) 
        std::cout << ' ' << m.value;
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
 1 2 3
```

If you want to use it with hash based containers (like `unordered_set`), you can similarly add a `std::hash<MyType>` class that will be used per default for your type.

Comment: @Aconcagua True, I modified it slightly.

Answer (score 1):

Because the comparator is not necessarily a function (function pointer, even). In fact, the default value for that parameter is `std::less<Key>`, which is a class template with an `operator()`. But you could pass the type of anything that can be called with two `MyType const&` and return a `bool`, hence the need to specify what that thing actually *is*.